# MySQL regex update query

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, database

I currently persist fully qualified class names in a table column but have changed this functionality in the backend to persist simple class names.

I need to update the fully qualified class names to simple names in the database but not sure how i would do it using REGEXP

I want to update column data and change `com.test.models.core.SomeFilter` to become `SomeFilter`

so getting the text from the last full stop and updating the column.

Comment: No regex needed. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE filter_table SET filter_name= SUBSTRING_INDEX(filter_name, '.', -1);
```